# I am trying to remember the name of a card game

Tags: identify-this-game

Here's everything I can remember about it:

I believe I first found it on the Pagat website.

I think it's a trick taking game, there are 5 (perhaps less or more?) different hands of play and I think the dealer chooses one of them based on his hand and throughout the course of the game the dealer must pick each of them once, being unable to choose the same one twice.

Each player has there turn choosing one of the "hands" to play until all players have picked each hand once then the game would end.

The one other thing I remember are the rules stating something about making a chart for each hand and player and marking off when each hand gets played to keep track of what's been picked and what's left to play.

Barbu has somewhat of the ideas here but that's not the game I'm looking for.

Comment: Sounds a little like Nyet, but I don't think it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the game is [Trex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trex_(card_game)), also known as Trix, Tricks, or Ticks.

The game is played by four players and consists of four cycles of five games each. During each cycle, a new player is the dealer. The dealer chooses in which order the five contracts are played (one in each game).

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trex_(card_game)) notes that it's similar to Barbu.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think that this game matches the poster's description?